# PhpStorm autocomplete new file and class not work

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I create new file in PhpStorm, it does not complete anything and the page is blank.

For example, when I create a class named `Database` it should create a file with this ready code

```
 <?php


class Database{


}
```

but nothing happened and the page is empty.

Comment: Are you creating a class file or php file?

Comment: Please also note that if you will simply create a new file, it will be empty by default. In order to have the pre-filled file with PHP tags and/or class you need to create New > PHP File or PHP Class.

Comment: i create PHP Class but it not pre-filled and be empty

Comment: Have you paid for a JetBrains license? I've always found their tech support to be extremely helpful.

Comment: What happens if you use menu `Code -> Completion -> Basic`? Does it show anything for you?

Comment: thank you @zoonman but i mean in a new PHP page create.

Comment: @Barmar no i,m not paid. are Phpstorm free or paid?

Comment: I didn't realize they made it available for free. I just checked their site and see that it's free for students and open-source projects.

Comment: All JetBrains products are available for free trial, after you have to settle with the license based on usage purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about code templates. In such case I recommend you to visit JetBrains [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-and-code-templates.html) and ensure that you have your templates installed correctly.

Please, check your template and see, if it is set like this:

[image: PHPStorm tempate]
If you have it setup correctly, you should be able to see a prompt for a class name and namespace, please, fill out the form and PHPStorm will generate the file for you. If it does set correctly, try to reinstall the software.

Please, check if you are using actual version of PHPStorm and have a license for it.

If none of this will help, use menu `Help -> New Support Request`. JetBrains has a very good support team.

UPDATE1:

**PHP Class** template

```
<?php
#parse("PHP File Header.php")

#if (${NAMESPACE})

namespace ${NAMESPACE};
#end

class ${NAME} 
{

}
```

Now switch to Includes tab. There should be template like this
[image]

**PHP File Header.php** template content (file name and extension must match the one from `#parse()` directive):

```
/**
 * ${PROJECT_NAME}
 * ${FILE_NAME}
 *
 * PHP Version 5
 *
 * @category Production
 * @package  Default
 * @date     ${DATE} ${TIME}
 * @license  http://${PROJECT_NAME}.com/license.txt ${PROJECT_NAME} License
 * @version  GIT: 1.0
 * @link     http://${PROJECT_NAME}.com/
 */
```

I recommend you to reinstall PHPStorm, it should have those templates.

Comment: if i want to do that i do not ask question here

Comment: i type <?php 

#parse("PHP File Header.php")

#if ({$NAMESPACE})

namespace ${NAMESPACE};
#end

class ${NAME}
{
} in where you show. but when i create new class error show and say            Error parsing file template: Encountered "$NAMESPACE" at <unknown template>[line 5, column 7]
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    "}" ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...

Comment: This sounds like it cannot parse your template. It is possible you've mistyped something. I will update my answer with exact content.